# Как правильно обратиться к значениям в json через dot-notation

Tags: jquery, json

Сконвертировал xml в json при помощи [скрипта](https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON):

```
{
    "offers":[
        {
            "offer":[
                {
                    "attr":{
                        "airline":{
                            "value":"Аэрофлот"
                        },
                        "airline_code":{
                            "value":"SU"
                        },
                        "title":{
                            "value":"Во Францию от 18662 рублей! Специальное предложение от авиакомпании Аэрофлот"
                        },
                        "id":{
                            "value":22098
                        },
                        "href":{
                            "value":"https://www.aviasales.ru/offers/vo-frantsiu-ot-18662-rublei-spetsialnoe-predlozhenie-ot-aviakompanii-aeroflot"
                        },
                        "sale_date_begin":{
                            "value":1483488000
                        },
                        "sale_date_end":{
                            "value":1484092800
                        },
                        "flight_date_begin":{
                            "value":1483488000
                        },
                        "flight_date_end":{
                            "value":1490400000
                        },
                        "link":{
                            "value":"https://hydra.aviasales.ru/adaptors/special_offer?iata=SU&utm_source=www&locale=ru&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aeroflot.ru%2Fru-ru%2Fspecial_offers%2F"
                        }
                    },
                    "description":[
                        {
                            "text":[
                                null
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions":[
                        {
                            "text":"<ul><li>Цены на авиабилеты указаны с учетом топливных, аэропортовых и государственных сборов.</li><li>Количество авиабилетов на каждом рейсе по данному тарифу ограничено.</li><li>Полные условия продажи авиабилетов на сайте авиакомпании.</li></ul>"
                        }
                    ],
                    "route":[
                        {
                            "attr":{
                                "from_iata":{
                                    "value":"MOW"
                                },
                                "to_iata":{
                                    "value":"PAR"
                                },
                                "from_name":{
                                    "value":"Москва"
                                },
                                "to_name":{
                                    "value":"Париж"
                                },
                                "class":{
                                    "value":"эконом"
                                },
                                "oneway_price":{
                                    "value":null
                                },
                                "roundtrip_price":{
                                    "value":"от 18662 рублей"
                                }
                            },
                            "text":[
                                null
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Проверил на валидность json-строку - валидна. Пытаюсь получить доступ к значениям полей - ошибок нет, а значит доступ к значениям есть. Но почему-то эти самые значения не выводятся.

```
for (var p in json.offers.offer) {
    if (i == 9) break;
    i++;
    sps.append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' +
        '<a class="special-card-link" title="' + json.offers.offer[p].attr.title.value + '" href="' + json.offers.offer[p].attr.link.value + '" target="_blank">' +
        '<div class="card offer">' +
        '<div class="card-content">' +
        '<img class="special-offer-card-image" src="//pics.avs.io/180/50/' + json.offers.offer[p].attr.airline_code.value + '.png" alt="' + json.offers.offer[p].attr.airline.value + '"/>' +
        '<div class="flight-detail">' +
        '<h6>' + json.offers.offer[p].attr.from_name.value + '</h6>' +
        '<h6>' + json.offers.offer[p].attr.to_name.value + '</h6>' +
        '</div>'
    );
}
```

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Вы принципиально отладчиком не пользуетесь?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский каким отладчиком?

Comment: Ну программисты пользуются такой волшебной штукой, как отладка (debugging). Очень помогает выявить ошибки в коде, особенно в сотнях классах и десятках тысячах строках кода.... Не сидят же все с бубном или не поют шаманские песни, чтоб у них всё заработало и не кидают каждый раз код на SO)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну каким, например, вы пользуетесь отладчиком? Мой отладчик - console.log() в браузере.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin developer tools в браузере умеют куда больше чем просто console.log, их инструментарием полезно научиться пользоваться) Ну там хотя бы на уровне брейкпоинт поставить, скоуп переменных посмотреть, выполнить команду на участке с брейкпоинтом.

Comment: Console.log — это не отладка........ ну сложно это отладкой назвать...... почитайте хотя бы https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome и вообще что devtools браузера умеют делать и не только браузера...ведь отладка ведется на всех ЯП, а значит не только в браузере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас что `offers` что `offer` — массивы. Значит надо либо пробегаться циклом по `json.offers`, а внутри циклом по `offer`, либо, если у вас всегда в `offers` будет только один элемент, то пробегаться по `json.offers[0].offer`  и работать с нулевым элементом.

Если в очень кривом случае, то ваша вещь будет выглядеть как-то так:

```js
var json = {
    "offers":[
        {
            "offer":[
                {
                    "attr":{
                        "airline":{
                            "value":"Аэрофлот"
                        },
                        "airline_code":{
                            "value":"SU"
                        },
                        "title":{
                            "value":"Во Францию от 18662 рублей! Специальное предложение от авиакомпании Аэрофлот"
                        },
                        "id":{
                            "value":22098
                        },
                        "href":{
                            "value":"https://www.aviasales.ru/offers/vo-frantsiu-ot-18662-rublei-spetsialnoe-predlozhenie-ot-aviakompanii-aeroflot"
                        },
                        "sale_date_begin":{
                            "value":1483488000
                        },
                        "sale_date_end":{
                            "value":1484092800
                        },
                        "flight_date_begin":{
                            "value":1483488000
                        },
                        "flight_date_end":{
                            "value":1490400000
                        },
                        "link":{
                            "value":"https://hydra.aviasales.ru/adaptors/special_offer?iata=SU&utm_source=www&locale=ru&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aeroflot.ru%2Fru-ru%2Fspecial_offers%2F"
                        }
                    },
                    "description":[
                        {
                            "text":[
                                null
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions":[
                        {
                            "text":"<ul><li>Цены на авиабилеты указаны с учетом топливных, аэропортовых и государственных сборов.</li><li>Количество авиабилетов на каждом рейсе по данному тарифу ограничено.</li><li>Полные условия продажи авиабилетов на сайте авиакомпании.</li></ul>"
                        }
                    ],
                    "route":[
                        {
                            "attr":{
                                "from_iata":{
                                    "value":"MOW"
                                },
                                "to_iata":{
                                    "value":"PAR"
                                },
                                "from_name":{
                                    "value":"Москва"
                                },
                                "to_name":{
                                    "value":"Париж"
                                },
                                "class":{
                                    "value":"эконом"
                                },
                                "oneway_price":{
                                    "value":null
                                },
                                "roundtrip_price":{
                                    "value":"от 18662 рублей"
                                }
                            },
                            "text":[
                                null
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var i = 0;
    var sps = $('#sps');
    var offer = json.offers[0].offer;

    for (var p in offer) {        
        if (i == 9) break;
        i++;
        sps.append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' +
            '<a class="special-card-link" title="' + offer[p].attr.title.value + '" href="' + offer[p].attr.link.value + '" target="_blank">' +
            '<div class="card offer">' +
            '<div class="card-content">' +
            '<img class="special-offer-card-image" src="//pics.avs.io/180/50/' + offer[p].attr.airline_code.value + '.png" alt="' + offer[p].attr.airline.value + '"/>' +
            '<div class="flight-detail">' +
            '<h6>' + offer[p].route[0].attr.from_name.value + '</h6>' +
            '<h6>' + offer[p].route[0].attr.to_name.value + '</h6>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sps"></div>
```

Comment: Если сделать так, то уже начинают появляться ошибки. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: ничего не знаю, всё работает. вы видимо сделали не так, как написано у меня в коде ибо я его подредачил до верного..... и да.....чтоб понять где это выскакивает вам поможет, угадайте......отладчик))

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin специально вставил в сниппет, для подтверждения слов

Comment: Да, действительно. Я пропустил кое-что. Спасибо за подсказки с отладчиком! Я и не знал, что браузер так умеет.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin там еще очень много всего. но отладчик один главных инструментов. читайте.  оооочень пригодится